# how to change icon of notification using cordova-plugin-firebase?

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm using cordova-plugin-firebase and I the icon appear good when the notification received in the header bar, but when I put the slide of the phone down to see the notification the icon appear different white square inside black circle.
So any body know how I find this solution depending on the plugin itself, but I don't undestand it .

> /res/native/android/res/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <!-- inherit from the holo theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>
    <drawable name="notification_big">@mipmap/icon</drawable>
    <drawable name="notification_icon">@mipmap/icon</drawable>
</resources>
```

> and
>   /res/native/android/res/values-v21/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>
    <drawable name="notification_big">@mipmap/icon</drawable>
    <drawable name="notification_icon">@drawable/ic_silhouette</drawable>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the icon is white there is something wrong with the resolutions, retio, etc. Try to follow the specifications or use this [link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html) to generate the proper icons for all resolutions.
 I personally tried to create styles.xml in the mentioned folders with no effect. It looks like you should create a hook that copy the data during compilation. How to do this you can find in [here](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/53#issuecomment-304573222).
In my projects I use the "100% working" method to change the default notification style:

1. Create the icons following the specifications or generate using external tools such as the generator mentioned above.
2. Copy created icons into 
   **[cordova_root]/platforms/android/res/drawable-[screen_resolution]/[icon_name.png]** before build, so the folder looks like [cordova_root]/platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/myicon.png (screen_resolution could be: drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi or other).
3. When you will send the notification from your server to firebase server, specify the icon name as the name of the previously created icon without file extension. 
   For example, if the name of your icon is: "myicon.png", on the server object icon name will be "myicon" without extension. For c# it looks like: 
   `new Notification = {
          Body = "Hello world",
          Color = "red",
          Icon = "myicon",
          Sound = "default"
       };`

Comment: Sorry for answering with the links, but the original comment contains more then 2 links and I can make an answer only with maximum two links